# Global Error Handler for Flash Player 10.1 not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, error-handling, global

Trying to implement the new FP 10.1 Global error handler into my projects but no matter what I do any uncaught error will still show up the Exception window (both in debug and release versions of the SWF). All I want to do is to prevent these popups but instead send a message to my logger. Here's my code ...

EDIT: I simplified the code now. Could somebody do me a favor and test the following class and see if it's works for him? Because it's doesn't for me! ...

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.UncaughtErrorEvent;    

    public class GlobalErrorHandlerTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function GlobalErrorHandlerTest()
        {
            stage.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);
            throw new Error();
        }           

        private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void 
        {
            var message:String;
            if (e.error["message"])
            {
                message = e.error["message"];
            }
            else if (e.error["text"])
            {
                message = e.error["text"];
            }
            else
            {
                message = e.error["toString"]();
            }

            trace("Uncaught Error: " + e.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as above - I was referencing stage.loadInfo, believing that as that references the stage, it would capture all uncaught errors. However, that doesn't work, you have to actually follow grapefukt's suggestion verbatim: On the actual base display object, place the code

`loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.add...`

When you try to place onto `stage.loaderInfo` or `frame.loaderInfo`, it has no effect.

In my case, I had to place it in the class that extended the base display object. Very Odd.

Comment: I wish that would work but, alas it does not for me. I've added the event listener directly to my base display object. Normally this code should be caught by it, right? ...

`setTimeout(function():void
{
 throw new Error("foo!");
}, 3000);
`

But it doesn't. Also I suppose it should work the same way for AIR as for web-based Flash?

Comment: Haaarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr!!!! I know now what the problem was with this. It was a misunderstanding! The event handler was called but the error would still bubble up and opens the exception window in Flash player. So the solution to that is event.preventDefault()!

Answer (score 1):

The docs say that:

> The UncaughtErrorEvents object that dispatches the event is associated with either a LoaderInfo object or a Loader object.

Thus you must listen to the `loaderInfo`'s `uncaughtErrorEvents` property of your topmost display object:

```
loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);
```

Comment: Still no luck! I'm out of ideas! Can _anyone_ confirm that the above example works for them??

Answer (score 0):

You must set up the listener not to a specific view, but to the main stage object, as it's at the top of the display list (thus picking up any exception of any of its children).

Comment: The 'view' is actually the top-most display object container (it's just given as a property to my Main class). And neither does it work if I use view.stage.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I think I may know why you think this isn't working. I made the mistake of testing inside the debugger. When the debugger stopped on the runtime errors I assumed that this proved my uncaughtErrorHandler function was not working. In fact, this was in error. It's just a quirk of the debugger. The debugger will still stop as if it is an unhandled error or exception, but if you press Run again you'll see it DOES execute the error handling code. See my thread [Flex 4.0/4.5 global error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024247/flex-4-0-4-5-global-error-handling-problem) for more info.

Original response:
I am looking for this same info. None of the examples in the API doc nor various blogs on the subject work for me. I've tried just loaderInfo, stage.loaderInfo, systemManager.loaderInfo... It makes no difference. I even tried all of them in a single test case! The addEventListener are being set but the uncaught errors are not firing the uncaughtErrorHandler. Argh. I have wasted far too much time on this! I've reduced it to a very simple program much like above except with all the code in the main mxml file.

How about this: can someone post a Global Error Handling example that DOES work? I'm using Flex SDK 4.1 (I've also tried with 4.5), targeting FP 10.1 (or 10.2 for 4.5), in a mx:Application-based mxml Flex project.

My thread: [Flex 4.0/4.5 global error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024247/flex-4-0-4-5-global-error-handling-problem)