# Flex 4.0/4.5 global error handling

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, error-handling, global

I'm trying to use the new(ish) AS3 global error handling class. I am trying to use it within a Flex mxml application. I can't get it to work at all. Below is an entire program that shows the problem. I set this to use Flash Player 10.2 and compiled with the Flex 4.5 SDK.

I've tried using Flex SDK 4.0 and 4.5 but I get the error in either case. I must be missing something obvious here. This is a normal Flex SWF file that will be shown on a web page. Assuming I could import the UncaughtErrorEvent, I would then do something like this to setup the event handler:

```
    if(systemManager.loaderInfo.hasOwnProperty("uncaughtErrorEvents")) {                   
        IEventDispatcher(
            systemManager.loaderInfo["uncaughtErrorEvents"]).addEventListener(
               "uncaughtError", uncaughtErrorHandler);
    }
```

this all seems horribly kludgy but I could live with that except that it doesn't work! I've scoured the web and cannot find any docs or examples that explain how to make this work in my context. Any advice?

Complete program:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete="onApplicationComplete();"
                   >
        <fx:Declarations>
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        </fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                private function onApplicationComplete() : void {
                    systemManager.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener("uncaughtError", uncaughtErrorHandler);
                }
                private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:Event) : void {
                    trace(event.toString());
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <s:Button x="153" y="64" label="Trigger Error" id="triggerButton" click="throw new Error('myError')"/>
    </s:Application>
```

Comment: Try using stage.loaderInfo instead of systemManager?                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315904/global-error-handler-for-flash-player-10-1-not-working

Comment: Hmm, that thread just confirms the problem I am having. It just doesn't work regardless of which loaderInfo I addEventListener on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take from the [API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) (which I recommend you look through next time):

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
                       applicationComplete="applicationCompleteHandler();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            import flash.events.UncaughtErrorEvent;

            private function applicationCompleteHandler():void
            {
                loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);
            }

            private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
            {
                if (event.error is Error)
                {
                    var error:Error = event.error as Error;
                    // do something with the error
                }
                else if (event.error is ErrorEvent)
                {
                    var errorEvent:ErrorEvent = event.error as ErrorEvent;
                    // do something with the error
                }
                else
                {
                    // a non-Error, non-ErrorEvent type was thrown and uncaught
                }
            }

            private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                throw new Error("Gak!");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="Cause Error" click="clickHandler(event);"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Wow, nothing worse that a rude response! Obviously I did read the docs since my code was cut directly from them. It does not work. As you can see from other threads, I am not alone. I only posted after reading the API docs and trying at least 5 other suggestions from various blogs. Something is wrong with either the function or all the documentation. I have a 30 line complete program that shows this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm curious: did you try your code? First, it didn't compile. I had to change WindowedApplication to Application. Then I had to set the target FP to 10.1. Then it compiled, but gave the exact results as my code. THere are logic errors in your program too. It needs to call event.preventDefault() in the error handler. So I think you are placing far too much faith in the documentation since I tried every example I could find and none worked as expected. I am still trying to figure out why you concluded I didn't read the API docs since my example is almost identical to the one in the API ref.

Comment: Rude response? I just said you should look through the API. If you did, good for you, but you didn't mention it or showed the same code. Yes, I did try it, works fine if you follow the documentation (WindowedApplication is Air, and API says minium FP is 10.1). It doesn't *need* to call preventDefault(), that's an added plus if you just don't want an error box to pop up.  But yeah, the example shown here works perfectly.

Comment: Hmm. I ran the sample completely unchanged with the exception of changing the word WindowedApplication to Application. The code in the error handler is never called and the program aborts on the runtime error. Seeing the other threads about this it is clear other people are having this problem. So why is it that the code above doesn't even work for me? I've been doing my tests in Flash Builder 4 using SDK 4.1 and SDK 4.5. I guess I'll try it in FB 4.5 as well. But there is something clearly missing in the instructions since this isn't working for many people.

Comment: In the compiler settings, make sure you specify it's for Flash Player 10.1 and over.  Also, with the code above, the error box will still show since we're not intercepting the event, we're just catching it, so if you had a trace within it, it would display in the console.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help J_A_X. There is still something I'm missing because even after setting target player to 10.1 or higher this doesn't work in a web page context. So this is the exact demo source above with WindowedApplication changed to Application. The only other changes I made was to set the compiler to 10.1 FP, Flex SDK 4.1, and added a trace statement to the uncaughtErrorHandler. It never executes the error handler. As I said, there are other threads documenting this same problem so something isn't working.

Comment: The other 'threads' you're referring to are people that aren't coding it properly.  Can you please post your code exactly?  What's happening that it "isn't working"?  I tried with Flex 4.0, 4.1 and 4.5, all with success so long as Flash Player 10.1 is required.

Comment: J_A_X, the code above doesn't work. Add a trace statement to the first line. Then trigger the error. The trace statement never executes. Add a event.preventDefault() prior to the call. The trace never executes. I have tried every example I can find on the web and none of them work with Flex 4.1 or 4.5 SDK when compiled into a SWF. Even the simplest program doesn't work. I've seen GEH work in AIR apps, but at this point I cannot get it to work with web-destined SWF files.

Comment: Hey J_A_X, my apologizes and thanks for sticking with me on this. So I dug a little deeper. The reason I thought even your sample code above didn't work has to do with the behavior in the debugger. In the debugger it stops on the runtime error like a breakpoint and displays the error. I had placed a breakpoint on my trace statement in the uncaughtErrorHandler. Since it stopped with the runtime error and not on my trace statement I concluded that the example "wasn't working". However, I pressed Run after the first breakpoint and shazam it stopped on my trace statement. So all is well after all!

Answer (score 3):

```
    <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                           uncaughtError="uncaughtErrorHandler(event)" />
```

The easy way...