# AS3 Loading external swf from AN externally loaded swf - Accessing Children?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external, parent-child

EDIT

### UPDATE MARCH 12TH 2012: This is done using AIR FOR ANDROID USING CS5.5. I need access to the vars in the newly **EXTERNALLY LOADED SWF** files that are hosted on a web server and I need to have the APP on my phone access them. **I am beginning to this is not possible.**

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

***My Main Stage swf loads another one:***

**SWF 1**

```
var TheContent:Loader = new Loader();
    TheContent.load(new URLRequest("http://MyWebsite.com/swf2.swf"));
```

/// In this **SWF 1** above **I NEED TO KNOW WHAT CODE** can see if other content is loaded and control it when loaded. But its tricky because **I am loading external content from an externally loaded swf.**

***Here is the code in SWF 2***

```
var TheMenu:Loader = new Loader();
TheMenu.load(new URLRequest("http://MyWebsite.com/MenuBar.png")); // you were missing a "
```

In the first **SWF 1** I want to know if the MenuBar.png has loaded and how to control it. So for example in **SWF 1** I might put code like this...

```
    if(TheContent.MenuBar) /// IS LOADED? THEN...
    {
        MenuBar.alpha = .3;
        MenuBar.x = 33;
        etc...
    }
```

Comment: I don't have time to try this out and post a real answer ATM but look into adding event listeners to the loaderInfo object that belongs to your Document Class, or the root container object for your application. Some more nfo on working with this object can be found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315904/global-error-handler-for-flash-player-10-1-not-working and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html. It's only a theory but, it might be possibly to globally intercept all LOADED events through this object.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the progress value into a public variable, that can be acessed through the swf.

The follow code for SWF 2:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class YourClassName
{
    /**This will get a progress number of your file**/
    public var fileProgress:Number = 0;
    /**This will get the file size**/
    public var fileTotalBytes:Number = 0;

    public function YourClassName()
    {           
        var TheMenu:Loader = new Loader();
        TheMenu.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler, false, 0, true);
        TheMenu.load(new URLRequest("http://MyWebsite.com/MenuBar.png"));

    }

    protected function onProgressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void{
        fileProgress = event.bytesLoaded;
        fileTotalBytes = event.bytesTotal;
    }
}`
```

The follow code for SWF 1:

```
public function printStatus():void{

        //Returs file`s progress
        trace("Progresss: "+swf1.fileProgress);

        //Return file`s size
        trace("File size: "+swf1.fileTotalBytes);
    }
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Thanks for your time. This will not work because it will only allow me to tell when the second clip is loaded... but not when the second clip loads the 3rd. Also I need to get access to control these clips once loaded. But thanks so much for your crack at it.

Answer (score 0):

First Point, it seems that your whole structure is proberly not the best approach. From my under standing your question is:

(Main Movie) loads secondary(Movie) then (SECONDARY) Movie  loads its secondary (movie);

then you want the first movie to control the second movie on condition the third movie is %100 and ready for action

This will target from the loaded Swf to the main SWF

```
      MovieClip(parent.parent).ParentFunction();    // or the 3rd movie would be 
      MovieClip(parent.parent.parent).ParentFunction();
```

I have made you a file on my server   http://www.gamezslave.net/SampleAS3/

Just open the main movie.swf you will see it load the other two movies inside of each other as you wanted then it plays an animation in the first movie to let you know the 3rd movie has finished downloading. Let me know how you go please as i took 15 minutes putting it together for you.

in the zip (contains all source files 3x "SWF" and 3x "html pages");

thanks BJM Sydney

Comment: Hi Parele, I am so grateful for  your time on this. I tried the files and they work GREAT "locally" but I uploaded "Second.swf" and "Thrid.swf" onto a server and am calling from my ANDROID app and these can not access the functions on the main timeline. I have tried like crazy to figure this out so I made this post. I figured if the 2 loaded files can't access the root maybe I can make the root control the 2 loaded files once they are loaded. If you know how to do this on Air For Android and with the two swf files on a server that would be AMAZING! Thanks again for your wonderul effort.

Comment: check here , http://www.gamezslave.com/PapaDeBeau/  The files are on my server and working, Make sure all your files are in the same directory on your webserver

Comment: Thank you parele. Yes they work on my server too.. however, when I load them from my DROID phone and place the other two loaded swf files ONLINE. It does not work. However I recoded and got a work around but I am missing one line. Can you look at this and see if you can help me with THIS ONE LINE? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715798/as3-externally-loaded-swf-from-network-to-control-externally-loaded-swf-from-net