# Get Child of loader from externally loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parent-child

READY? Here it is:

```
var TheLoader:Object = parentObj.TheExit as Object;
```

This line gets me to the swf I loaded and I can now change the alpha, move it etc...

**BUT HOW HOW HOW... do I get one of its children and control get that same control?**

Example Code:

```
TheLoader.TheChild.alpha = .3; // Does not work!
```

5 days on this issue is WAY TOO LONG! Here is the 3rd post with the same issue but more detail. [as3 externally loaded swf from network to control externally loaded swf from network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715798/as3-externally-loaded-swf-from-network-to-control-externally-loaded-swf-from-net)

I just made this shorter to get attention to the ONE LINE I NEED!!!

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html), you'll see that it has a `content` property. This is how you access your loaded content. So, for example, if `TheLoader` is a Loader, and if `TheChild` was an instance on the timeline of the loaded SWF, you could do:

```
var child : Sprite = MovieClip(TheLoader.content).TheChild;
```

This child is not available until the content has been actually loaded, so be sure to listen to for the COMPLETE event on the Loader's `contentLoaderInfo` before accessing the content:

```
TheLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(event : Event):void
{
    trace(MovieClip(loader.content).theChild);
}
```

Also note that you may run into security issues if the loader and loadee SWFs are not on the same domain. In this case, you will have to call [`Security.allowDomain`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain%28%29) in the SWFs to allow the cross-scripting.

Comment: Awesome. Oh man. I will try. I hope this works. I will let you know asap. Thanks

Comment: BAM! That was it! 5 days for that one line. Amazing Thanks brother. I hope this answer can help others save the time I spent on this.

Comment: THE FULL QUESTION AND CODE IS HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715798/as3-externally-loaded-swf-from-network-to-control-externally-loaded-swf-from-net/9747976#9747976

Comment: Just a note...you can also listen to the stage for the child to be added (if you know its type), which will happen in good time.