# as3 AIR for android - Application-sandbox content ERROR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, security, air

**THE GOAL:**

I am trying to allow externally loaded swf files communicate with each other that are locally loaded from the device. I need to be able to have access to vars and functions and objects. I have accheived this while loading swf content from the web here: [as3 externally loaded swf from network to control externally loaded swf from network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715798/as3-externally-loaded-swf-from-network-to-control-externally-loaded-swf-from-net)

**BUT WHEN I GIVE THE USER THE OPTION TO LOAD FROM DEVICE OR FROM ONLINE**... The device swf files can't communicate with each other. Specifically the loaded swf can not get info from its parent.

Below is the code that works when loading from online:

```
var InsideConent:Object = this.parent.parent as Object; //// GIVES ACCESS TO "Content.swf"
var ItWorksNow:Sprite = MovieClip(InsideConent.TWO.content).ChildInTWO;  ///
```

The device doesn't like this code:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

But when run online it works fine. Below is the error I get when I run it locally loaded from the APP package.

**THE ERROR:**

SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.
    at flash.system::Security$/allowDomain()
    at Products_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
Cannot display source code at this location.

**THE QUESTION:**
Is there anything I can do to make allow security domain to work locally on an AIR FOR ANDROID device so I don't have to change my code?  - thanks

Comment: This one must be a tricky one. Nobody wants to touch it perhaps.

Comment: i'm facing a similar problem: can't find a way to get simple code using `Loader` to work when it's compiled in IDEAS on android. Global FlashPlayer Security Settings Panel redirect me to mobile flash plugin settings allowing only to set storage and p2p.

Comment: did you try to pass `LoaderContext` to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load() ?

Comment: No I didn't try it. I gave up and am working on learning packages now. But man oh man... so complex for my little brain. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put a try catch around that line it won't throw an error if it fails. And this way when your code will work on the web and as an app. (apps don't need to allowDomain b/c they can download everything by default and that is why it fails.)

`try {Security.allowDomain("*");}catch (e) { };`

Comment: No worries, i was pondering the same thing but i could never get it solved because i couldn't modify the source swf.... heh. This is the solution i would have applied.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you can load remote swfs from another domain that is configured correctly with the crossdomain xml.
something like: https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/guide/using-crossdomain-xml.htm

You can load  swf with code,
but if you try to access the stage for example it will fail.

Also, if in your original project (hosted all on a web server, you used common static variables or singeltons, it will not succeed.
My solution was adding functions on those files which receive the objects I needed to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't execute code from loaded swfs in AIR, you can still use multiple swfs to dislay assets but any code will give that error.

Comment: Actually you can. My First swf is an AIR FOR ANDROID and all the others are regular swf files and each can communicate with each other.. ie get size and control objects in other movies. It works on my DROID but I have a feeling it won't work on apple. I have not tested it yet. I know you can't load external swfs and have them run code with apple. So I have heard.

Comment: yes, but those SWFs are bundled with your APP, and Baris was referring loading SWF's out of your sandbox.