# How to pick up parameters from Flex Application, inside external, locally stored SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am using LoaderMax to load and display various assets (videos, images and SWFs)

The SWFs are saved locally and need to access parameters passed on via my Flex Mobile app.

This project was previously built in Flash Pro, and the code:

```
var foo = root.loaderInfo.parameters['foo'];
```

worked perfectly before.

Now I am in Flex (and using LoaderMax) I am unsure how to pass the parameters along/pick them up.

When LoaderMax loads the SWF, I get:

> SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access
>   this feature.     at flash.system::Security$/allowDomain()

I tried using:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

but the app seemed to freeze on the splash screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try with this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425505/as3-air-for-android-application-sandbox-content-error). is apparently the same problem. in this link use this code:

```
try {Security.allowDomain("*");}catch (e) { };
```

I hope it will be helpful.