# ApplicationDomain woes. Dynamically loading local .swfs from a shared library into separate projects. Failed casts

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have two projects, `A` and `B`, that reference a library, `MyExternalLibrary`.  `A` and `B` are `.swf`s (two different AS3 projects) and `MyExternalLibrary` is a `.swc`.  When my application is run, `A` loads `B`.

There is a `Class`, `MyLoader`, in `MyExternalLibrary` that `B` uses extensively.  `MyExternalLibrary.MyLoader` loads `.swf`s that are present on our server (we don't embed them because they are loaded dynamically per user-request).

Note that our server contains `A`, `B` and all of the `.swf`s we are going to download.

Now, `A` must also load some of the `.swf`s on our server.  Consequentially, `A` must also use `MyLoader` in `MyExternalLibrary`.  So, In `A`, I add a reference to `MyLoader`, so that its binary is included during compilation.  I only add a reference to `MyLoader` -- I don't actually instantiate or modify it.  That is, somewhere in `A`'s code (before `B` is loaded), I have:

`MyLoader;`

I (obviously) import the `Class` as well. This ensures that `MyLoader`'s binary will be included in `A`'s `.swf`.

Just referencing `MyExternalLibary.MyLoader` in `A` breaks `B`'s functionality with `MyLoader` -- all of the `.swf`s that `B` loads will not `cast` to its associated `Class`, despite being a `MovieClip` and having all of the proper fields.  Furthermore, in the debugger, the loaded `MovieClip`s show that they are of the correct `Class`.  For example, if I load a `.swf`, it will be a `MovieClip`; moreover, the debugger states it is of type `B.mySwfs.MyClass`, but I cannot `cast` it to `B.mySwfs.MyClass`.  I believe the culprit is `ApplicationDomain`.

Note that commenting out that line of code makes everything in `B` `cast` properly.

If anyone has any idea about what's going on, I'd love some advice. I think that this issue deals with `ApplicationDomain` since `A` *owns* `MyExternalLibrary.MyLoader`, and I'm trying to `cast` a `MovieClip` loaded by `A` into a `Class` that is in `B`.  When I comment out all references to `MyExternalLibrary.MyLoader` in `A`, `B` now *owns* `MyExternalLibrary.MyLoader`, so it is able to cast to classes in `B`.  That is my hunch!

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify your question: If SWF `B` uses the `MyLoader` class extensively, why must you be including that unused reference to `MyLoader` in swf `B`?  You also state that SWF `A` loads SWF `B` -- so but then in the 2nd paragraph you state "somewhere in B's code (before A is loaded)...".  Maybe the A's and B's are mixed up in the question?

Comment: PS: Generally, there is no side effect to doing this... Unless, you make changes to the SWC code, and only recompile the SWC and SWF `A` (for example).  SWC `B` then has an "outdated definition" of the class and this type of problem may occur.

Comment: Sunil, my goal is to integrate loading external files between `A` and `B` using the same `Class`, `MyLoader`.  Currently, `B` uses `MyLoader` and `A` uses a bunch of mumbo-jumbo.  While refactoring, I encountered many errors (as aforementioned) when `MyLoader` was used in `A`.  With further testing, I realized that the adding simple statement: `MyLoader;` to `A` caused `MyLoader` to break in `B`.

I have not made any changes to `MyExternalLibrary` or `MyLoader`, but I will make sure that both `A` and `B` reference new versions of `MyExternalLibrary`.

Comment: As a tip, if B will only be executed within A and both A and B make use of MyExternalLibrary, then you could make B reference MyExternalLibrary as external (shared library), so you only compile it in A. That way you make sure B will always use A's definition of the library. Also, check out ApplicationDomain docs, they could be useful for what you are doing.

Comment: How do You load SWF ? Do load them into same application domain ?

Comment: I agree with Sunil, you're question is very confusing, and it seems like `A` and `B` are mixed up.  Also try including actual error messages instead of "breaks B's functionality" or "nothing works in B".

Comment: @JeffWard I just re-wrote most of the question, and I hope everything is easier to understand.

Comment: @Cay I tried using an `external` library as per your advice; however, that didn't work since `B` uses a lot of `Class`es in `MyExternalLibrary` that `A` does not include.  So, at run-time, `B` complains it is missing references to `Class`es in `MyExternalLibrary` since `A` didn't include the binary for such `Class`es.

Comment: @turbosqel As mentioned by everyone, I believe the culprit is `ApplicationDomain`. I've been reading the `ApplicationDomain` doc and fiddling with `LoaderContext` to no avail.  If anyone has any expertise with `ApplicationDomain` and think they can provide a hand, please do so!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715798/as3-externally-loaded-swf-from-network-to-control-externally-loaded-swf-from-net/9716236#9716236 , check this answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to ensure that `B`'s `ApplicationDomain` is the same as `A`'s `ApplicationDomain`.  This is done by parameterizing an instance of `LoaderContext` in either `Loader.load` or `Loader.loadBytes`.

For example, `A` loads `B` with the following line of code:

`m_loader.load(new URLRequest("B.swf"), new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));`

This adds all of `B`'s `Class` definitions to `A`.  So, when `A` loads a `.swf`, and that `MovieClip` is `cast`ed to a `Class` in `B`, everything will work because `A` and `B` are in the same `ApplicationDomain`.  So, an `Object` loaded by `A` can be `cast`ed to a `Class` that is in `B`.

If anyone else encounters this problem, I highly suggest taking a look at GreenSock's SWFLoader: http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/loading/SWFLoader.html